# How to set lifecycle for Assembly Scan method in StructureMap?

Tags: c#, .net, inversion-of-control, structuremap

I want to set life time to Assembly scan 
I have a class that type of Registery(structure map) but i can't set life time to all classes that registerd by structure map 
this is my code:

```
public class ServiceLayerRegistery : Registry
{
    public ServiceLayerRegistery()
    {
        Scan(scanner =>
        {
            scanner.TheCallingAssembly();
            scanner.WithDefaultConventions();
            scanner.AssemblyContainingType<myService>();
        });

    }
}
```

I want to set Container scoped life time to all registered class but by default Transient life time Applied

Answer (score 2, accepted):

if you want set life time for non-generic classes use below code:

```
        Scan(scanner =>
        {
            scanner.TheCallingAssembly();
            scanner.WithDefaultConventions().OnAddedPluginTypes(c=>c.ContainerScoped()));
            scanner.AssemblyContainingType<myService>();
        });
```

but if you want to set life time for generic classes open below link:
[How to set lifecycle on types connected with ConnectImplementationsToTypesClosing](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2169083/10227866)